# Load forecasting using LSTM

Tags: regression, forecasting, deep-learning, matlab, lstm

I am using MATLAB 2018a, and looking for an explanation, or pointers, on how can I modify the matlab example for "sequence to sequence regression" to use it with "double" type predictor data array Xtrain of size 9x823 and "double type" response data array Ytrain of size 1x823.

The example is for cell type data array, I couldn't translate the code to be used for double type data array.

My goal is to forecast load using this example.

Example link: [Sequence-to-Sequence Regression Using Deep Learning](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/examples/sequence-to-sequence-regression-using-deep-learning.html)